# Asterisk and fake number - how to identify ?

Tags: logging, asterisk, sip, phone-call

With Asterisk, I guess it is possible to make a call with a "fake" number (for example, your phone number in the company is 123456 and the call you make will only show the main number of the company, 123400).

As a normal person, I get spam calls. And it's boring me.

Therefore, I'd like to find a way to identify the true carrier or the true origin for a call.

For example, I get a call from a false number (+33 6 xx xx xx xx) that might be coming from France, but the number is wrong (not given by any phone provider). So, I'd like to know if it's possible to get the origin of the call (the country, the provider or, the real number).

Any help is welcome : solution, conf file, documentation, tips, iso standards.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is - *you* can't...

If someone has access to the PSTN at the SS7 level to set there own (incorrect) caller ID it's down to the Telco who provide the access to the originating party. As the recipient of a call and a normal user you have *no* way to trace that call back to its origin. You telco may be able to assist if they are threatening or abusive calls, if for example you are in the UK then you can register with the Telephone Preference Service, report your concerns to Ofcom or the Information commissioners office who will investigate - but will not tell you the true origin.

If the calls come via SIP/AIX/MGCP etc then you may be able to deduce something from the IP address which initiated the call(s) or shows up in the headers, but again there is no 100% way to trace where the calls have come from.

If you use asterisk and you are receiving calls from 'invalid' caller ID's my best suggestion is to blacklist them in your `extensions.conf` file.

This rule for example blocks anyone sending a caller ID starting with `087` and the one below blocks lazy system admins who send `unavailable`

`exten => s,2,GotoIf($["${CALLERID(num):0:3}" = "087"]?103:3)
exten => s,7,GotoIf($["${CALLERID(name):0:11}" = "UNAVAILABLE"]?103:8)`

These have been pulled from a running config - if you need an entire config section post a comment and I'll anonymize a version and update my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would have prefer that it would be possible, since spammer are using each time a different fake number (and blacklist a number that is used only one time couldn't prevent the next one).

Comment: If the numbers all come from something *very* invalid then you could write a more complex rule which matches digit lengths and validity. I don't have an example to hand but If you have a google for regex/paten matching you should find something.

Comment: The numbers are correct, but there is no real line behind that number (when I call a number, I got a signal of 3 tones, or the pstn provider said that the number is not reachable).

Comment: Not sure which country your in but I'd make a rule as mine above which starts something like `exten => s,2,GotoIf($["${CALLERID(num):0:3}" = "012"]?103:3)` which would block att numbers coming in starting `012`

Comment: I'm from France. So the normal calls either start with 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 09, or 033 (+33). And the spam calls are "shown" as normal calls. For example, a guy from another country want to spam call me : he has a regular number, from his country (maybe an american spammer : so his regular number is 001 xxx yyy zzzz), but when he spam call me, the number that is shown on my phone is 033 x aabbccdd. And that number may be a regular number for someone, or it may be a number that is not yet given to a normal french person. That is what I call a fake number.

Comment: Hmmm... Are these calls coming via the PSTN or SIP? The only easy routes I could think to look at is send all calls to an IVR and force the person to interact - they may kill off some spammers, I'd still put a rule to check for valid CLI only (even if that allows spammers through it may catch some who send very obviously wrong cli.